# bad interpreter when setting up virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv

So I have done the install for virtualenv but when I try to create my folder this is what I get:

```
desktop duwaynew$ virtualenv someone -bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv:        /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv creation in windows:

http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html

virtualenv creation in ubunutu(Linux platform)

Install pip using `sudo apt-install pip` and `pip install virtualenv`

create a env ( example global ) `virtualenv global` , and activate

`source global/bin/activate`